# HIVE SQL: Avg for last three dates for each user_id

Tags: sql, subquery, hive, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has three columns.  'user_id', 'date', 'number'.  Here is a sample table:

```
user_id    date          number
a          2000-01-01    100
a          2003-03-08    50
a          2004-04-21    10
a          2004-12-11    10
a          2010-03-03    10
b          2000-06-29    1
b          2002-05-22    2
b          2002-07-06    3
b          2008-10-20    4
```

What I would like to return is a unique list of 'user_id's and an average of the 'number' for each user for only the most recent three dates.

So I would like to see for user_id: a, avg: AVG(10,10,10)=10 and for user_id:b, avg: AVG(2,3,4)=3.  In table form:

```
user_id    avg_3
a          10
b          3
```

I'm at a loss on how to do this in HIVE SQL.  So far, all I have is a total average HIVE query:

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(number) FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id
```

----EDIT----

After looking at this link: [extract top n records in each group.](http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/). I've come up with the following possibility, but Hive does not like it (error: Invalid function 'rank').

```
SELECT b.user_id, avg(b.number)
FROM
(
   SELECT a.user_id, a.number, a.date, rank(a.user_id) as r
   FROM (
        SELECT user_id, date, number
        FROM table_name
        DISTRIBUTE BY user_id
        SORT BY user_id, number desc
        ) a
) b
WHERE a.r < 5
GROUP BY b.user_id
```

-----EDIT #2-----

I just realized the 'rank' function is a user-defined function in Hive.  Hence, Hive does not recognize it.  Does anyone know a way around this without UDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Hive 11+, which introduces windowing functions.

```
SELECT b.user_id, avg(b.number)
FROM
(
   SELECT user_id, number, date,
          row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) r
   FROM table_name
) b
WHERE r <= 3
GROUP BY b.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that this works.  Although our IT department does not have this version of Hive.  I'm currently trying to get PIG to do this instead.

As a Hive SQL side note, another longer and more complicated way to do this is to use left inner joins and select the max dates such that the previous max date column is NULL.